# Git revert fails on pull

Tags: git

I broke my script with a git commit. I was able to reset it with this command and get it working again:

```
git reset --hard 148cdea0c52 && git clean -f
```

But when I do a git pull, the script breaks again. How do I make this working commit the current commit for this branch?

Comment: You should try `git revert` instead of `git reset`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your `reset` command is not producing the expected result is that the `reset` command actually resets your current HEAD of the current branch to a specified state/commit (e.g., 148cdea0c52). But when you do `git pull` again, your current HEAD goes to the original HEAD that contains the buggy commit that you want to get rid of.

A quick fix can be - after resetting the HEAD, you can do a force push to update the HEAD of your remote branch.

The cleanest way to do this is to run

```
git revert <commit-id>
```

*** Here, `<commit-id>` should be the commit that introduced the bug. `git revert` will create a new commit by reverting the changes from your original commit. After that, you can push your current HEAD to the remote repository so that remote repository also has the latest fix.

You can also run `git rebase -i` command to silently discard the previous commit. Then do a force push to update the remote repository. Although, I will strongly discourage you to do so unless you exactly know what are you going to do.